# Is there a way to create a keystore file on Tezos that is similar to Ethereum's keystore V3?

Tags: javascript, crypto

Talking about this specifically: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#encrypt

Takes a private key and outputs a JSON keystore file.

Comment: I'm not aware of any, Taquito is the most popular library, you could open a feature request for them: https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito . Kukai web wallet exports a keystore file and the code is open source, you can copy that if you like

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick implementation based on Kukai's model:

```
import { Curves, generateSecretKey, InMemorySigner } from "@taquito/signer";
import { mnemonicToSeedSync, validateMnemonic } from "bip39";
import * as scrypt from "scryptsy";
import * as cryptob from "crypto-browserify";
import * as forge from "node-forge";

interface Keystore {
  encryptedSeed: string;
  iv: string;
}

export class TezosKeystore {
  private _mnemonic: string;
  private _passphrase: string;

  constructor(words: string, password: string = "") {
    this._mnemonic = words;
    this._passphrase = password;
  }

  async encrypt(encryptionKey: string, hdWallet: boolean = false) {
    const seed = await this._extractSeed(this._mnemonic, hdWallet);
    console.log(1, 1, seed);

    const encrypted = await this._encrypt(seed, encryptionKey);

    return { encryptedSeed: encrypted.chiphertext, iv: encrypted.iv };
  }

  async decrypt(
    keystore: Keystore,
    decryptionKey: string,
    derivationPath: string = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/0",
    curve: Curves = "secp256k1"
  ): Promise<string> {
    const decryptedSeed = await this._decrypt(
      keystore.encryptedSeed,
      decryptionKey,
      keystore.iv
    );
    console.log(1, 2, decryptedSeed);

    return generateSecretKey(decryptedSeed, derivationPath, curve);
  }

  private async _extractSeed(mnemonic: string, hdWallet: boolean = false) {
    if (!validateMnemonic(mnemonic)) {
      throw new Error("InvalidMnemonic");
    }

    return mnemonicToSeedSync(this._mnemonic, this._passphrase).slice(
      0,
      hdWallet ? 64 : 32
    );
  }

  private async _encrypt(
    plaintext: any,
    password: string,
    salt?: string
  ): Promise<{ chiphertext: string; iv: string }> {
    if (!password) {
      throw new Error("Missing password");
    }
    let salty;
    if (salt) {
      salty = Buffer.from(salt, "hex");
    } else {
      salty = cryptob.randomBytes(16);
    }
    const key = await scrypt.async(password, salty, 65536, 8, 1, 32);
    const cipher: any = forge.cipher.createCipher(
      "AES-GCM",
      key.toString("binary")
    );
    cipher.start({
      iv: salty,
    });
    const byteStringBuffer = forge.util.createBuffer(
      plaintext.toString("binary"),
      "utf-8"
    );
    cipher.update(byteStringBuffer);
    cipher.finish();
    const chiphertext = cipher.output.toHex() + "==" + cipher.mode.tag.toHex();

    return { chiphertext: chiphertext, iv: salty.toString("hex") };
  }

  async _decrypt(
    chipher: string,
    password: string,
    salt: string
  ): Promise<Buffer> {
    try {
      if (!password || !salt) {
        throw new Error("Missing password or salt");
      }
      const parts = chipher.split("==");
      const chiphertext = parts[0];
      const tag = parts[1];
      const key = await scrypt.async(
        password,
        Buffer.from(salt, "hex"),
        65536,
        8,
        1,
        32
      );
      const decipher: any = forge.cipher.createDecipher(
        "AES-GCM",
        key.toString("binary")
      );
      decipher.start({
        iv: Buffer.from(salt, "hex"),
        tag: forge.util.createBuffer(
          Buffer.from(tag, "hex").toString("binary"),
          "utf-8"
        ), // authentication tag from encryption
      });
      decipher.update(
        forge.util.createBuffer(
          Buffer.from(chiphertext, "hex").toString("binary"),
          "utf-8"
        )
      );
      const pass = decipher.finish();
      if (pass) {
        return Buffer.from(decipher.output.toHex(), "hex");
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```